# Azure Mobile App Offline Sync never got data

Tags: c#, sqlite, azure, windows-store-apps

I'm creating Windows 10 Store application and I have a problem when calling `PullAsync` method. I was using Azure Mobile App for a long time and I always used `private IMobileServiceTable<MyTable> table`. Now, I need to add support of something in Microsoft called `Offline Sync`. Following instruction, I didn't succeeded.

Here's my code.

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Sync;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.SQLiteStore;

private IMobileServiceSyncTable<MyTable> OffTable = App.MobileService.GetSyncTable<MyTable>();
private IMobileServiceTable<MyTable> OnTable = App.MobileService.GetTable<MyTable>();

protected ovveride async OnNavigatedTo()
{
    if(!App.MobileService.SyncContext.IsInitialized)
    {
        var store = new MobileServiceSQLiteStore("localstore.db");
        store.DefineTable<MyTable>();

        await App.MobileService.SyncContext.InitializeAsync(store);
    }

    await OffTable.PullAsync("uniqueID", OffTable.CreateQuery());
    var data = await OffTable.ToCollectionAsync();    //return -> nothing

    var data2 = await OnTable.ToCollectionAsync();    //return -> 50 rows
}
```

And `MyTable.cs`

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices;
using Newtosoft.Json;

[DataTable("MyTable")]
public sealed class MyTable
{
    [JsonProperty]
    public int ID { get; set;}


    [JsonProperty]
    public string Field1 { get; set; }

    //...

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "version")]
    [Version]
    public string Version { get; set; }


    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "deleted")]
    [Deleted]
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }


    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "updatedAt")]
    [UpdatedAt]
    public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; }


    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "createdAt")]
    [CreatedAt]
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
}
```

Here's values from `project.json`:

```
"Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client": "2.0.1",
"Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client.SQLiteStore": "2.0.1"
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Problem was on the server side.
So, basically you need to create Table via Azure Portal. You can create via `SQL Management Studio` as well, but when creating via Portal, you will have `createdAt`, `updatedAt`, `version` and `deleted` in right format. So, if you created table via `SQL MGMNT Studio`, go to Portal and click `Create Table`, enter your table's name. It's OK, your data **WILL NOT** be overwritten and then everything should work fine.